# Element with text set via jQuery wraps for no apparent reason

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some DIVs and LIs that I am setting the text of via jQuery.

Such as

```
var answers = ['Participants will be added and  invited to this team', 'A Sign Up Sheet will be created'];
$('#inv-type').text(answers[value]);
```

or

```
$('#summary').append('<li>'+answer+'</li>');
```

In both cases, the text wraps when assigned to the DIV or LI although in both cases there is plenty of room for the text to not have to wrap.  Here's the DIV inspected:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Very difficult to judge without seeing the rest of your code. Can you make a minimal test case on JSBin if you don't have your code live?

Comment: Strange. I tested your code on a fiddle, not seeing the same problem http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/R3R35/. Have you inspected what is actually inserted into the `<div>` - e.g. are there any line breaks and etc? Also, what is the computed style of the `<div>` element?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it eithe.  I create a fiddle too and it's not happening there http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/EFcdN/1/  I'm not sure what's causing it.